# SwiftUI how to update List dynamic

Tags: ios, list, foreach, swiftui

I'm using SwiftUI just started. I often confused how difference between Declarative programming and Imperative programming.

Console log show error：

> ForEach<Range, Int, Text> count (2) != its initial count (1).
> `ForEach(_:content:)` should only be used for *constant* data. Instead
> conform data to `Identifiable` or use `ForEach(_:id:content:)` and
> provide an explicit `id`!

Why？How to update list dynamically？How dose SwiftUI handle data source？

```
struct TestView: View {
    @State var n = 1
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button.init("update") {
                self.n += 1
            }
            AView.init(n: n)
        }
    }
}

struct AView: View {
    let n: Int
    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0..<n) { i in
                Text.init(String(i))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ForEach(_:id:content:)` differs from `ForEach(_:content:)` by the `id` parameter.

If you use a static `ForEach` the loop is generated once and not refreshed when you modify the `n`.

Try this:

```
struct AView: View {
    let n: Int

    var body: some View {
        List {
            ForEach(0 ..< n, id:\.self) { i in // <- add `id` parameter
                Text(String(i))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can take a look at [Why does .self work for ForEach?](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/why-does-self-work-for-foreach) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Thank you. But I have a similar problem take me a lot time. Maybe hope you would make some tips.  [How to change complex data source in swiftUI List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62737523/how-to-change-complex-data-source-in-swiftui-list)

Comment: @avemarina Sure, but please create a new question. I've already answered this one. And please look at [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)